# After copying files using gsutil, they are not deleted instantly from the local storage

Tags: cmd, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

My task is to upload CSV files from the local database to the `Google Cloud storage`.

To do this, I first copy them to my desktop and then upload them to the `Google Cloud storage`.

I want this to be done automatically, without my participation. Therefore, I created a CMD file that will be run by `Task Scheduler`. The structure of the CMD file is the next:

```
gsutil cp C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\*.csv gs://my-bucket

gsutil rm C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\*.csv
```

But after loading data into `Google Cloud storage, it does not delete the CSV files.

**However**, if you run the delete in a separate command, it **successfully deletes** files.

Just:

```
gsutil rm C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\*.csv
```

But I want the download and removal code to be in one file.

I also tried this way (but it did not help me either):

```
gsutil cp C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\*.csv gs://my-bucket

del C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\*.csv
```

What are the solutions to this problem?

Comment: If the `gsutil` command is a .bat or .cmd file, then you need to use `CALL gsutil...`. See also https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/233

Comment: @lit, but upload gsutil command works fine without `CALL`

Comment: Why do you use seperate cp/rm commands instead of [gsutil mv](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) ?

Comment: @LotPings, hm... I haven't known about this command but it seems that it is working fine. Thank you! Please write your solution in the answers section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [gsutil mv](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) command is designed for this use case.

Note, however, the [docs section about atomicity](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#non-atomic-operation). Especially with moving from your local filesystem to the cloud, there is no way to upload and delete atomically, so the command will first upload, verify the file is stored in the cloud, and then delete the local file.

Comment: Nice answer! To quote the relevant part of the non-atomicity of it here: _"[gsutil mv] performs a copy from source to destination followed by removing the source for each object. A consequence of this is that, in addition to normal network and operation charges, if you  move a Nearline Storage, Coldline Storage, or Archive Storage object, deletion and data retrieval charges apply."_

Answer (score 2):

The problem is cause by `gsutil` being a script. On Windows, this script (gsutil) exits and stops further processing of commands in your batch file.

The solution is to add the word `call` in front of `gsutil`:

```
call gsutil cp C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\test\*.csv gs://my-bucket
```

Next, do not use `gsutil` to delete a local file. Use `del` instead.